# Devilspie2 KeePass2 Compatibility

Tags: gnome, xorg, keepass, devilspie

I use keepass2 to manage passwords (hence I want it always on top and pinned to all workspaces and that core reason I installed devilspie2).

While I am able to to both "pin" and "position" the keepass window according to its window class and/or application name (both work)... after, I open an "Edit Entry" window,  the "pin" to functionality simply stops working for the keepass application and none of the solutions below will get it work consistently.

These can pin and position the keepass window prior to opening an "Edit Entry" window:

```
if (string.match(get_application_name(), "KeePass2")) then
     set_window_geometry(960, 500, 960, 500);
end

if (string.match(get_application_name(), "KeePass2")) then
     pin_window();
end

if (string.match(get_application_name(), "KeePass")) then
     set_window_geometry(960, 500, 960, 500);
end

if (string.match(get_application_name(), "KeePass")) then
     pin_window();
end

if (string.match(get_window_name(), "Edit Entry")) then
     set_window_geometry(960, 500, 960, 500);
end

if (string.match(get_window_name(), "Edit Entry")) then
     pin_window();
end

if (get_window_name() == "Edit Entry") then
 pin_window();
end
```

**NOTE:**
the positioning of "Edit Entry" is not vital... it cannot be changed outside of devilspie2 as well. Also if I stop and restart devilspie2 with the "Edit Entry" window open... it immediately starts working.  If I close the "Edit Entry" and open a new "Edit Entry", devilspie2 stops working (no pinning) and devilspie2 needs a restart.

Also something odd that I noticed is that the application name changes when an "Edit Entry" window is open (hence the use of both "Keepass" and "Keepass2" above.

When "Edit Entry" window is -NOT- open and a database is  -NOT- open debug shows:

```
Class: KeePass2
Application: KeePass
Window: KeePass
```

When "Edit Entry" window is -NOT- open, but a database is  open debug shows:

```
Class: KeePass2
Application: PrivateDBNName.kdbx - KeePass
Window: PrivateDBname.kdbx - KeePass
```

When "Edit Entry" window is open debug shows:

```
Class: KeePass2
Application: KeePass2
Window: Edit Entry
```

Obviously, positioning and pinning the Keepass windows according to their window class names seems the most intuitive, but doing so just results in the same problem that I describe above, where after opening the "Edit Entry" window devilspie2 simply stops working for KeePass altogether, thereby defeating the purpose installing it and doing this much to configure it :-/.

Any advice appreciated.

**Something Interesting**
The output of this command shows something odd for keepass:

```
$ wmctrl -lx
0x06a000f8  2 gedit.Gedit           localhost debug.lua (~/.config/devilspie2) - gedit
0x0260005d  2 keepass2.KeePass2                        N/A PrivteDBName.kdbx - KeePass
0x026009a2  2 keepass2.KeePass2                        N/A Edit Entry
```

--the hostname is always missing, whether keepass is working or not working

**Yup Pesky Bug**
So I installed KeePassXC via PPA and the first thing I did was run:

```
$ wmctrl -lx
0x07800006  2 keepassxc.KeePassXC   localhost PrivateDBName - KeePassXC
```

**Another Bug**
While the positioning and pinning with KeePassXC now works.  After I actually create a new password entry in the database, devilspie2 again stops working.

So that is now two different versions of KeePass  (fairly popular app) that will not work correctly with devilspie2 pinning.  But somehow fractional scaling is a higher priority than the commonly user expected ability to position and pin a window.. :-/ going for ice cream... avoiding "the devil."

**Pleasant Update:**
deleted Keepass2 and rebooted machine.. now KeePassXC pinning continues to work after I create a new db entry... buggy dependency libraries?

--The localhost name -does- exist.

I configured devilspie2 and **-almost-** everything works exactly as expected.   hint, hint post #3 coming shortly.

Minus the window height setting, the following works:

```
if  (get_window_class() == "KeePassXC") then
     set_window_geometry(960, 500, 960, 495)
     pin_window();
end
```

Side note:

This app really seems like something that gnome/ubuntu should natively incorporate since it provides such a high value-add in terms of usability.  I am sure many users would choose this position & pinning windows via an accurate GUI over fractional scaling any day. (just my humble opinion)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with KeepassXC, which I use. Perhaps also try grouping the two rules within a single if ..then ..end statement: if ... then (newline)      set_window_geometry(960, 500, 960, 500); (newline)    pin_window(); (newline)
end

Comment: Wonderful. So I have a discovered a bug with KeePass2/DevilsPie2/X11 and the only work around is to change to KeePassXC.  Its mind boggling that DevilsPie2 functionality isn't native to gnome-desktop/ubuntu, but okay if I don't want to loose X hours of trouble shooting Deveilspie2, then I have to make the switch.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I just created a new database entry in KeePassXC...  and immediately the pinning functionality of devilspie2.. simply stopped working...  so frustration limit hit.. enough of devilspie2.. will update my my post wrap up this adventure in hell

Comment: **Pleasant Update:**
deleted Keepass2 and rebooted machine.. now KeePassXC pinning continues to work after I create a new db entry... buggy dependency libraries?